# Fetch the Max date record for each year or an item

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table with data below.  There are almost seven years worth of data in this table.  Each Item has at least 52 rows of data.

```
INV_TAB

ITEM_ID END_DATE        QUANTITY
--------    ------------    ----------
10      07-JAN-2008 100
10      14-JAN-2008  85
10      21-JAN-2008  60
... ( other 2008 rows )
10      31-DEC-2008  72
... ( 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 rows )
10      31-DEC-2013 130
10      23-AUG-2014  56
20      07-JAN-2008  10
... ( 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 rows )
20      31-DEC-2013   2
20      23-AUG-2014  11
...
```

What I can't seem to figure out is a SQL query (Oracle) to retrieve for a specific item all the final (or last) rows for each year.  Using the data above my result
for item 10 would be 7 rows returned:

```
ITEM_ID END_DATE        QUANTITY
--------    ------------    ----------
10      31-DEC-2008  60
... ( 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 rows )
10      31-DEC-2013 130
10      23-AUG-2014  56
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You can try to group all lines by years and use analytics function to display the first data order by end_date desc

Comment: Why would "6" be the result for item 10? Is that a count of rows, or a total of some column, or what? You talk about wanting the "last" row for each year, but how does the "6" relate to the "last" row? And how are you deciding what "last" means?

Comment: Bob Jarvis - You are correct 6 is incorrect it should be 7 rows returned for Item 10.  I really only want to 2013, but I am fine with getting the latest 2014 record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the last row for each year with this query:

```
SELECT IT.*
FROM INV_TAB IT
INNER JOIN (SELECT I.ITEM_ID
                  ,MAX(I.END_DATE) AS [END_DATE]
           FROM INV_TAB I
           GROUP BY I.ITEM_ID, DATEPART(YEAR,I.END_DATE)) T ON T.ITEM_ID = IT.ITEM_ID
                                                    AND T.END_DATE = IT.END_DATE
```

Hope this is what your are looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help you to find a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ROW_NUMBER()` like this:

```
SELECT
      ITEM_ID
    , END_DATE
    , QUANTITY
FROM (
            SELECT
                  ITEM_ID
                , END_DATE
                , QUANTITY
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_ID, TRUNC(END_DATE, 'YYYY')
                                     ORDER BY END_DATE DESC) AS rn
            ORDER BY END_DATE
            FROM INV_TAB
      ) 
WHERE rn = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` simply issues integers starting at 1 increasing by 1. The OVER() clause specifies when to re-start at 1 (that's the partition by) and then order by controls the sequence of the increasing numbers. So if I get the question correctly you want a 1 for each item_id at each end-of year.

Comment: Thanks!! This worked.  I need to read more on the row_Number and partition by functions.

Comment: great, upvote perhaps? Start with documentation on `Analytic Functions` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174